# Preventing object literals type widening when passed as argument in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, generics, arguments, type-inference, object-literal

Is is possible in the lastest TypeScript version to pass an object literal as argument to a function without widening it, and also without using `as const` in the invocation?

link to TS Playground: [Example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABKSAeAKgPgBQDcCGANiAKYBci6AlBeogN6ICwAUIu4gE4lQidIFiJANysAvqJatCPRFBIBnKIgC8ycBGyMA1iQCeFAOSDShxGKqsA9Fbl6ADiUQwwwEp24ATRPgUNEugaISpwuAObCYta2CgAWRISIAEZOOvoUAEQmJBnC5qwFLDLK8koATKrqkFoB6YjGRKY+fhAISuaWLDZ2js6u7l7N-oGZ2bn5UkWypVAAzJUommlBDUJmYkOtYO2d3VAOTi5uHiTevv7c+J4IhHq1QVmNOXlRk4XRNt0AtnDciK1fewyAAeiBIwPwgJkiDgwEQAHd4soYF85Jw9OE5HBENcyIUtu0vooFPgwopKvRWBx-pd5J4jPQwJCSBt4ecILTTsEQBAIMTQIRbgA6QwAGipHG6Qul4k2bWUhX2vQASiQgfg+QA1J4KVAASTA9hAynB8jAnj8IXCosQqvVfKJYCgflNJHNfkYAG0RsEoKEwGEALoUK0B8yIAA+iHAnhIwBcp0wqgl7ANRpNwLNFsQAAMACT0I7uRAAZRLUHwnCgYgAOvQC0XOIgANL6WtiBv9Jsl1VKMQ5xAAfkQ3RgcJgyiUMEFiHifnwiGyWOSTm49tOKdtasIGpIjudYMzbuzXp9oaDIb9mI2w9H48nsBnc58XG3u-3fig2JcCncUE3+b0GWFZVh29B2juDpus6nqtnogaHlmlpXmGw4Qe+0EKLB+gIZkMZxgmngZCOtjxOa0JQLEq5vlBTqIGAcDKMAcAxv8vhOOCQIwBAE63LO7hOF+Pi4HAMDePCYlupiQmGOehibmB6FajqqA9ooUA2kpe6YUm3TcBAfAKDAuAkHxa6QU4CQwpRxbZH4LhyFRr7tLCjmHIaxoKTmm4UGmxokc4cLwk41x0fEJmvuu+59H0v5Vja3C8Pwbl9OmQwwAoPmIH5UB5HeCIhQgyjhU4dnLuZu4JTwfBIDZqX+ecGWFLGEA7n8iywAgyC-F8+BQAAssSpIkKgcGIcefiBK5SokK5RIKCSZIKDaAAKnBwPYLpHu6-jenU57Br6-phOYODzYtJBwRQcE2vY62bYOFBrRtCidNSZBadqQi6tgM1zUNS1UNh8E2ogAByCBgyAgr4EkMioH9cJ3S9mCYJI0jTOpAAsCw9X1g0LcN2AZByJB9acGQ2oyzKZOg6lfaQGQWNEPTuccgznLmBbnqy7Kct4Cg8nyC0CsK3ldLYP7yFcMJwhkMwM04bItPz3K8vy0PChkhTFHI6kAKy45wvUDQDJDE6T5NEVTTJErT9NPMR7LyszEus307Ncpz8sO0ICJ82TdJq8LCii3oQra5MuszAAbEbJsExdFv85TDC2+QiAZHTSiK0zcrbFAuy2DNHsDF7fg+znTz+yrgdcoL6si5r4cZEAA)

What I currently do is this:

```
function func<T>(value: T): T { 
    return value;
};

let test = func({ key: 'value' })
// type inferred as { key: string;}
```

what I want is the following

```
// ... alternative declaration of func

let test = func({ key: 'value' })
// type inferred as { key: "value"; }
```

More precisely it should work for any object literal extending `Record<string,string>`

These archive the result I want, but Id like not to change the way the function must be invoked

```
function func<T>(value: T): T {
    return value
};

let test = func({ key: 'value' as const })
// type inferred as { key: "value"; }

let test = func({ key: 'value' } as const )
// type inferred as { readonly key: "value"; }
```

Is this possible?

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/10676 seems to be talking about this:
"The type inferred for a property in an object literal is the widened literal type of the expression unless the property has a contextual type that includes literal types." 
But I don't quite understand how I could make the "contextual type include literal types" in my case, or what that means precisely

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. But the solution might seem unintuitive and redundant.

You will have to add another generic type to the function. This will keep will allow us to keep narrowed type of string literals passed to the function.

```
function func<T extends Record<string, S>, S extends string>(value: T): T { 
    return value;
};

let test = func({ key: 'value', a: "a" })
// let test: {
//     key: "value";
//     a: "a";
// }
```

We can apply this to your complex example.

```
declare function formatMessage<
  Key extends keyof typeof messages, 
  Props extends { [key: string]: S }, 
  S extends string
>(messageKey: Key, props?: Props)
    :ReplaceValues<(typeof messages)[Key],  NonNullable<typeof props>>;

let test4 = formatMessage("created", {name: "TestValue"})
// let test4: "TestValue was created successfully."
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABKSAeAKogpgDylsAEwGdEAlLCOAJ0NWKmpjAHMAaRAZQD4PPs8BEogZNW3ABQA3AIYAbEFgBcidAEoVmAN6IAsAChERxNSxQQ1JLIVYA3AYC%209-QblnE%20BogC8ycBAkdAGssAE8VAHJrRQiOGRUAIhkExAc1AwB6DI9QgAcsRGZgLGpTQkQZUmCwlVFmFlsHTOziAAt5OUQAIwLq8MQE6KwE21SDcf03KA8sBgAmHz9IQMQQ-qj5GIrSKjAvNOac-MKwYtKscsrEPsShkbGXSfdPKABmRZQAm8QNmwjU7aIXZedL6LJHApFEplQE6UwyQgIOShVY1AZ3UZNR4TZpZcEAWxoBSo%20NybhwAhkpLciDgwEQAHd2tMYPiPNRQvUPHBEIilBNgdN8bNiDIWLNFloDMYgfD8IRIlowFSsA5GVcIHKLiIQBAICLQHJkQA6WLS4zg41WxyAwV6R5QPIFChkmT6gBqm1mqAAkmBciBprh8ERSHVWBwXXI3VhhWAoKRg0IqogANprWqMeoAXUzYhYAIAPohwIQsMBmBduD5zUY-QGg4JQ4gAAYAEi0UOoXE4UBk1CgDgAOloO13EABpMLDhxj04lLgUBgOFuIAD8iHBMHpMGmDBgRsQ7VIMkQQ253QKpld%20sItfIWBvsYICYEIeEOnTaPDLFzIizrAAhuW47nusCHseFQmI%200b6nGr5QDyzDECUUD3u2WicL2-aDh2UYxvBxCplOoTZm%20yb-vm64Pk%20hHEWEZGJKW5aVoQKTgu0RA0lArRXjBBEvogYBwNMwBwKWQKVAUuBkjAEC7siR4lAUiEVFIcAwOUDKaQQXKqREP4RPes5aPhHpesQqCcEuUCRvxcEvsQ1bgqYEAWMQMBSFginXrBBQdLSPELkMpDMB4vHQV4dLhZC-qBsZLb3io9aBpu2TboyBSIvGR4yF50G0YJYXIahHCmOYlgxScDaAjAxBJYgKVQKMIGZbyCDTO0%20UhRevkxmVZgWEgQXValVx1RMZYQNGphLNA8BIGJ1D4jIUAALIimKWCoCR5HNms0WOvk0XCsQorisQHAAArUHAuSJk2H5phmlE5io-AOHwe3CD%20kinedWAkSoJEcLkt33WuKg3XdxCgjKShmVgno2JZEhHVgJ2bRdaj0aRHCIAAcggBMgEaMhdG4qDo9FYMw9w3DOK4zyzFAAAsHw0Ct61Y1gEgJJqWCrRcCQcEqKqJOgLPI4oCQHGC2RTDMDCsxLUteuqOxauUxC6vqZ2GiaCQTIrLwAKwc8tq0bWdW18wLQtsaLyrCqrDDS8MtoIMuoLgujJxnDCVwDC87sa7KgvyjqeoGqThvG8zDAAGwW1z1sA3bWsi9czvKAMktu16sue3sUA%209kftdoHpAJCH6sMhqWtR3rxAG6ExoJEAA)

---

Here are some further resources which helped me with problems like these in the past.

- [Typescript: Type Inference on function arguments](https://catchts.com/infer-arguments)
- [Suggestion: Const contexts for generic type inference](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30680) - This post describes a way to narrow down object literals of arbitrary shape.

Comment: Thank you so much, this is exactly what I was looking for. Do I get it right, that making the values of the parameter object a generic as well somehow marks the contextual type to include literal types as mentioned in the PR? Thus allowing it to remain narrow.

Comment: Yes, I suspect that is pretty much what is going on here.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else coming around this question: [ts-toolbelt](https://github.com/millsp/ts-toolbelt) has several utilities to help with this sort of type juggleing. In this case [F.narrow](https://millsp.github.io/ts-toolbelt/modules/function_narrow.html) is exactly what is needed to have the type be inferred unwidened, without the use of some sort of trick:

```js
import { F } from 'ts-toolbelt'

function func<T>(value: F.Narrow<T>) { 
    return value;
};
```

Also coming out in TypeScript 5.0 the "[const modifier](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/51865)" serves exactly this purpose of preventing type widening.